# Issue debugging NPM script in WebStorm?

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, webstorm

I have setup a debug configuration for my NPM script in WebStorm. It looks like this:

[image]

This script works after turning off/on my machine. It starts my server and I'm able to debug. But after some time, it stops working. Instead of the starting the server, I get this in my console output

```
/Users/<redacted>/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin/node /Users/<redacted>/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js run dev-<redacted> --scripts-prepend-node-path=auto
    Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:49847/9d8e55cd-db30-413c-91e2-27e9bda70d5a
        For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
        Debugger attached.

    > <redacted>-api@2.2.0 dev-<redacted> /Users/<redacted>/server-<redacted>
    > NODE_ENV=development USE_TOGGLES=true nodemon server.js

    Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:49851/4f719819-42d6-4540-9986-8035b6d1f62e
        For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
```

And then if I restart my machine, the debug script starts working again. Any suggestions what could be causing this?

When the server starts successfully, the console output looks like this (with many more messages following the ellipses)

```
/Users/<redacted>/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin/node /Users/<redacted>/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js run dev-toggles --scripts-prepend-node-path=auto
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:49523/28a29443-5b0e-4f26-8de4-35ef264699c2
    For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
    Debugger attached.

> <redacted>-api@2.2.0 dev-toggles /Users/<redacted>/server-api
> NODE_ENV=development USE_TOGGLES=true node server.js

Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:49527/3ca76918-4409-4244-afb7-2bb1c329e3bc
    For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
    Debugger attached.
    Application loaded using the "development" environment configuration with pid: 1745

2019-09-18T14:52:56.716Z - info: DEV: Using redis for jobs queue
2019-09-18T14:52:56.982Z - debug: will use /Users/<redacted>/server-api/app/locales/en.json
2019-09-18T14:52:56.982Z - debug: read /Users/<redacted>/server-api/app/locales/en.json for locale: en

.......
```

Comment: Please try disabling `js.debugger.use.node.options` key in *Registry...* (*Help | Find action*, type `Registry` to locate it) - what is the result?

Comment: It's strange, that your success case output uses node for starting the server, but fail case output starts with nodemon

Comment: @ykit9 I was playing with node vs nodemon in my npm script. It works with `nodemon` (and `node`) after a fresh restart.

Comment: @lena when I disable this option, my server does start succesfully. however, it no longer stops on breakpoints :(

Comment: when this option is disabled, you need adding `$NODE_DEBUG_OPTION` to your NPM script to pass `--inspect-brk=<port>` to node, like `node $NODE_DEBUG_OPTION server.js`...

Comment: also, the officially supported way to debug applications started with nodemon is using *Attach to a Node.js/Chrome* debug configuration - see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2019.2/running-and-debugging-node-js.html#nodemon

Comment: @lena when I add `$NODE_DEBUG_OPTION` my server doesn't start. And I get similar behavior when I try with "attach a node.js/chrome" -- after turning my machine on/off I am able to attach to a debugger to my runnning node.js server, but it stops working after a little while and I need to restart my machine again

Comment: not sure... can be https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-40496